# How to change parser titles when using Argparse without modifying internal variables?

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, argparse

I'm using Python's [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module to create a CLI for my application. I've made a `subparsers` variable to store the parsers for each command, but when I can't find a way to change the title of the `subparsers` without modifying `parser`'s (the main `ArgumentParser`'s) internal variables.

### Original Code

```py
parser = ArgumentParser(prog="pacstall", formatter_class=CustomHelpFormatter)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")

parser._subparsers.title = "commands"  # type: ignore[union-attr]
parser._optionals.title = "options"
```

#### Result

[image: original_code_result]

### Edited Code

```py
parser = ArgumentParser(prog="pacstall", formatter_class=CustomHelpFormatter)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="commands", dest="command")
parser._optionals.title = "options"
```

#### Result

[image: edited_code_result]

As you can see the order of the `options` and `commands` are switched if I make that change. Also I have no idea how to modify the `title` of the `_optionals` to `"options"` without modifying `parser._optionals.title`.

Here is my [full parser file](https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall/blob/4d135d9a709c51a34c709263a20f34b5995a799b/pacstall/parser.py).

Answer (score 0):

The `parser` gets 2 initial argument_groups, with titles 'positional arguments' and 'optional arguments'.  There's has been discussion about changing those, or giving users more control.  But as you found, you can change them directly.

I won't tell anyone if you modify `parser._options` :)

You can also create your own `argument_group` - that's documented.  You'll still get the default `--help` in the original (unless you disable that).

`subparsers` puts that argument in the 'positionals' by default.  If you specify a 'title', it makes a new group.

Groups are displayed in the order that they were created, or rather the order that they appear in the `parser._action_groups` list.  Look at `parser.format_help` to see how that's done.

Comment: > There's has been discussion about changing those

Can you link to that discussion?